# Unable to Edit Specific Entries & Publish Error as Super Admin

Tags: control-panel, error

I've got a complex site that was working until yesterday with no code changes in the last week.

EE 2.9.2

In the Branch Locator channel there are two specific entries which I am unable to make any changes, content, status, entry_date whatever even when logged in as super admin. On save there is no error and the publish page redirects as normal. However when viewing the edited entry none of the changes have been saved. This does not happen to any other entries or channels.

At first I thought it might be related to MX Title Control, but I disabled that extension and the error persisted.

Additionally when publishing a new entry, as a Super Admin, I get the following error.

> An Error Was Encountered You are not authorized to access this page

THere are various text input fields, one dropdown field, 3 playa fields and a google maps for ExpressionEngine geo coder field. There are currently 32 entries in this channel with two of them being uneditable.

I just updated all addons to the latest version and error continues.